# How to set the format of Date in R

Tags: regex, r, csv

**A general code which accepts all kind of data format in R.**

I am having problems in getting the date correctly.. My date data set is in dd-mm-yy format, stored in CSV file. When I am trying to run the following program I am getting wrong output.

```
df$date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$date,format='%d %m %Y'))
```

This is my output:

Instead of showing this in output screen

```
18-10-2000
```

it's showing :

```
[1] "0018-10-20"
```

Also, Can you please explain me how can I make my code accept all types of Data formats which are stored in CSV file, such as:

```
DD-MM-YY
MM-DD-YY
Month_Name DD YY
Month_Name YY DD
DD Month_Name YY
YY Month_Name DD

and other formats..
```

Comment: `as.Date('15-06-2015','%d-%m-%Y')` gives you a R 'date' object. Type `class('15-06-2015','%d-%m-%Y')` and you should see `[1] "Date"`. For the different date formats check the manuals. Google is your friend :-)

Comment: How would a program know the correct format of "01-02-03"? Is that January 2, 2003, February 3, 2001, February 1, 2003, March 2, 2001?

Comment: @PierreLafortune, it does not know. That's why you have to add a format parameter as well. :-)

Comment: I was addressing the OP @hvollmeier. They want a program that automatically knows the format.

Comment: @PierreLafortune The year will be given in full such as "01-02-2003" in your case..
The default would be DD-MM-YY. Such as in your case. Otherwise, the user should know which date format he/she require.
I have included a section in UI for selecting the time format for CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
x = "18-10-2000"
format(as.Date(x,format='%d-%m-%Y'), format='%d-%m-%Y')
y = "18-10-15" # means "dd-mm-yy"
format(as.Date(y,format='%d-%m-%y'), format='%d-%m-%y')
```

you can also check `?strptime` to get the list of other formats.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lubridate:

```
lubridate::dmy(df$data)
```

or in base R as.Date()

```
as.Date(f$LASTMODIFIEDDATE,format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

As for your other date formats, I would say check lubridate. The commands are flexible (ymd, dmy, etc). But if you date column contains all your mentioned formats, you will run into problems, a single function will not help.

Maybe someone with a good regex knowledge could help you format the column into one date format.